# Krypton WinForm controls are readonly in vs2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, krypton-toolkit

I've got an old project to modify which was designed with ComponentFactory's Krypton toolkit v 4.3.2.0.

I opened it with VS2017. 
No problems to build and run the project. 
But in design mode, I can't select any krypton controls on the form. Even if I change the form size, it gives `readonly control collection` exception.

Any idea?

Comment: Make sure your project have a reference to `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Design`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using VS2019. It seems to be an incompatibility because `KryptonHeaderGroup` doesn't accept child controls.

I've solved my problem with the code below on `MyFile.Designer.cs`:

```
kryptonHeaderGroup1.Panel.Controls.Add(new KryptonButton());
```

If you want to share your code, I could be more specific.